# Multiple product details based on the product id in spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm new in spring boot and angular. I want to build typical functionality used in ecommerce. It's about a display details with multiple photos for the previously selected product.

Everything I wrote to solve this case is below

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product_img")
public class ProductImg {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String path;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Product product;

    public ProductImg() {
        super();
    }

    public ProductImg(Long id, String path, Product product) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.path = path;
        this.product = product;
    }

    @Transient
    private Long prodId;
    
    public Long getProdId() {
        return getProduct().getId();
    }

    public void setProdId(Long prodId) {
        this.prodId = prodId;
    }
    

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String mainImg;
   
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", targetEntity = ProductImg.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<ProductImg> productsImg;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getMainImg() {
        return mainImg;
    }

    public void setMainImg(String mainImg) {
        this.mainImg = mainImg;
    }

    public List<ProductImg> getProductsImg() {
        return productsImg;
    }

    public void setProductsImg(List<ProductImg> productsImg) {
        this.productsImg = productsImg;
    }
}
```

Repoistory of ProductImg

```
@Repository
public interface ProductImgRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductImg, Long>{  

    List<ProductImg> findByProdId(Long prodId); 
}
```

ProductImgController

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ProductImgController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ProductImgRepository productImgRepository;  
    
    @GetMapping("/Img/{prodId}")
    public List<ProductImg> getById(@PathVariable("prodId")Long prodId){
        return productImgRepository.findByProdId(prodId);
    }
        
}
```

Postman view from ProductImgController

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "path": "assets/img/main/img_2/belt-1/3.jpg",
        "prodId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "path": "assets/img/main/img_2/belt-1/3.jpg",
        "prodId": 1
    }
```

Product.ts

```
export class Product{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    mainImg: string;
}
```

ProductImg.ts

```
export class ProductImg{
    id: number;
    path: string;
    prodId: number; 
}
```

Service.ts

```
export class ProductService {

  private Products="http://localhost:8080/api/products";
  private ProductImg="http://localhost:8080/api/Img";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getAllProducts(): Observable<Product[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Product[]>(`${this.Products}`);
  }

  getProductById(id: number): Observable<Product[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Product[]>(`${this.Products}/${id}`);
  }

  getAllProductImg(): Observable<ProductImg[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<ProductImg[]>(`${this.ProductImg}`);
  }
  
  getImgByProductId(prodId: number): Observable<ProductImg[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<ProductImg[]>(`${this.ProductImg}/${prodId}`);
  }
}
```

DetailsComponent

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  product: Product[] =[]
  productImg: ProductImg[] =[];
  productImgAllList: ProductImg[] =[];
  id: number;
  prodId: number;


  constructor(private productService: ProductService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.loadProductById(this.id);
    this.loadImgByProdId(this.id);
  }

  loadProductById(id){
    this.productService.getProductById(this.id).subscribe((data)=>{
      this.product = data;
    });
  }

  loadImgByProdId(prodId){
    this.productService.getImgByProductId(this.prodId).subscribe((data)=>{
      this.productImg = data;
    });
  }
}
```

My idea i that, get the id of clicking product and send it to the **loadImgByProdId** function, which will display the photos with the prodId number equal to previously selected number from the product.
But when i run the project i get the message from console:

> GET http://localhost:8080/api/Img/undefined 400

> core.js:4442 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status:
> 400, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/api/Img/undefined",
> ok: false, …}

I guess the reason is @Transient with used to ignore a field from serialization but i cannot found workaround of this issue.

I will be grateful for any help or idea for solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that problem in this function

```
 loadImgByProdId(prodId){
    this.productService.getImgByProductId(this.prodId).subscribe((data)=>{
      this.productImg = data;
    });
  }
```

you need to use **prodId** as a parameter instead of **this.prodId** like this

```
 loadImgByProdId(prodId){
    this.productService.getImgByProductId(prodId).subscribe((data)=>{
      this.productImg = data;
    });
  }
```